# What is the best way to create variable that depends on the state in react?

Tags: reactjs, variables, react-hooks

I want to create 2 variables that depend on state. What i want to achieve is self-explanatory in my code below.

```
const evenodd = () => {
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0)
    const handleClick = () => {
        setCounter(counter +1)
    }
    // initiate with var, let, const, or useRef?
    (?) even = counter*2
    (?) odd = counter*2+1
    return (
        <div>
            counter: {counter}
            even: {even}
            odd: {odd}
            <button onClick={handleClick}>add</button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default evenodd
```

between `var`, `let`, `const`, or `useRef` which one should i pick for my 2 variables that depend on state? and for what reason?

Comment: In your specific case, a const is good enough.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `useMemo` hooks

```
const evenodd = () => {
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0)
    const handleClick = () => {
        setCounter(counter +1)
    }
    const even = React.useMemo(()=> (counter * 2), [counter]);
    const odd = React.useMemo(()=> (counter * 2 + 1), [counter]);
    return (
        <div>
            counter: {counter}
            even: {even}
            odd: {odd}
            <button onClick={handleClick}>add</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, just learn useMemo a moment ago! it's good for complex function but in my case, my function is just a simple math operation. I think i'll go with const as @Ryan Le suggest.

Comment: I also suggested using `const` but I didn't mention it. @azhardifa